# Invalid hook call when trying to render a component after a Redux state change in jQuery project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I want to remove jQuery gradually from my project in favor of React. I'm trying to use functional hooks to update the view after the Redux state changes. I coded up a working example on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/traxico/pen/QWNjmOK). However, when I try to do this in my project, I get an invalid hook call error when trying to use a functional component. I seem to somehow have 2 versions of React, but I'm not sure why. Would this be caused by a webpack misconfiguration? Commenting out the call to useSelector in my comment supresses the error.

The console returns false for this check.

```js
console.log(window.React1 === window.React2);
```

```
npm ls react
-- react@16.13.1
```

```js
//package.json
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
```

```js
//.babelrc for babel 7
// Invalid hook call error persists if modules & targets are commented out and the defaults are used instead

    "presets": [
        [          
          "@babel/preset-env",
          {
            //turn off transpile to CommonJS 
            "modules": false,

            //allow native async await
            "targets": {
              "node": "10"
            }           
          }
        ],
        
         "@babel/preset-react", //parse jsx syntax
        
      ]    
}
```

```js
//webpack.config.js
//rules
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            },
```

```js
//MyUl.jsx
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';


window.React2 = React;
console.log(window.React1 === window.React2);

let liKey = 0
let li = (count) => {
    return <li key={liKey++}>{count}</li>;
};
let buildList = (count) => {
    let list = [];
    for (let i = count; i--;) {
        list.push(li(count));
    }
    return list;
};

export const MyUl = ()  => {
    const blockList = useSelector(state => state.blockList);
    let count = 4;

    return (
        <ul id='list'>
            <li>1st element</li>
            {buildList(count)}
        </ul>
    );
};
```

```js
//main.js
import React from 'react';
import { MyUl } from './MyUl';
ReactDOM.render(MyUl(), $('#blockLinks')[0]);
window.React1 = React;
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was missing the Provider component when I was rendering. "Invalid hook call" is a terrible description for this specific error.

```js
//main.js
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
          MyUl
          <MyUl/>
        </Provider>,
    
        $('#blockLinks')[0]
    );
```